# How do I load an alternative font for PIL ImageFont on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have successfully ported some Python code to App Engine that uses PIL's ImageFont and ImageDraw to generate a dynamic image. The only remaining problem is that the original code loads a TrueType font using a call like this:

```
titlefont = ImageFont.truetype("Verdana Bold.ttf", titlefontsize)
```

I can't just upload the font file and access it directly in GAE (at least I don't think I can?!). I guess it might be possible somehow to dump font data in a datastore blob, load that and feed it into PIL, but this seems less than elegant, and quite wasteful if everybody who uses PIL for image generation does the same thing. Currently I'm stuck with `ImageFont.load_default()` though, which gives pretty horrendous looking results.

Is there some clever way of working with alternative fonts in GAE PIL? Some additional API I'm missing that will return usable font objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any file in your applications directory will be uploaded along with your application when you deploy it.

So yes, you should be able to "just" access any file you need by keeping it in or under your application directory, moving it there if necessary.

If you want to serve those files, that's something different. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles

But try including your .ttf file where your app can locate it and it should just work.

Comment: Cool. Yep, it works - not sure why I thought it really wouldn't. I had actually tried this just quickly, but I somehow got the paths mangled and the font files were not being found for that reason alone. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Ah yes, the paths - in case this helps anybody - for example, I have my font files in a folder "fonts" in the root directory of my GAE application. My controller code however, which tries to access the file to load the font, is in a sub folder itself. I **must** use `fonts/Font.ttf` to access the file. Can't have `/fonts/Font.ttf`. Weird, because the path isn't really relative - at least not relative to the executing code. Had me confused. Can't access file in current dir either. Gotta have a "relative" path based on the root dir. Note to self, remember this now :)

Comment: The app's current working directory is the root directory of your app, not the module you're currently in - hence why a path relative to the root of your app works. An absolute path does not work because your app is not in the server's root directory.